# Renaming xml file extension using bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a directory which has many folder and each folder contains a list of XML files. I am writing a bash script that traverses through the files and renames the extension of the file to "manual" if the size of the file is greater than 65Mb. This is my first writing a shell script and I was able to write the code for traversing the files but I am having difficulty in the renaming part.

```
for file in $dir
do
   size=$(stat -c%s "$file")
   if test "$size" -gt "68157440"; then
      echo "Before Renaming...."
      echo $file
      echo "After renaming"
      mv *.manual `basename $file`.xml
      echo $file
   else 
      echo $file >> outlog.log
   fi
done
```

an example of $file is,

```
/apps/jAS/dev/products-app/BConverter/data/supplier-data/TF/output/Fiber Optics and Fiber Management Solutions/Fiber Optic Cable Assemblies.xml
```

Comment: You probably mean a *bash* script rather than "batch".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mv *.manual `basename $file`.xml
```

If you want to change the extension of `$file` from `xml` to `manual`, do instead

```
mv "$file" "${file%.xml}".manual
```

Answer (score 1):

What exactly is the *difficulty* you're having?

If it's white space in file names, try

```
mv *.manual `basename "$file"`.xml
```

Note that your script will not work if `*.manual` expands to more than one file name.

Answer (score 0):

No need for a script on this, combination of `find` and `xargs` should do the trick:

```
find . -size +65M  | xargs -IQ mv Q Q.manual
```

The little-used `-I` option to Xargs:

1. runs each input as a separate command, and
2. lets you replace the filename, so you can use it multiple time, ideal for a mv

Comment: Fails for file names containing `'`.